# App force stopped(proc killed) by ActivityManager immediately after it started, only on Lollipop(Samsung GALAXY Note III)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile, aidl

The Samsung GALAXY Note III is running Lollipop and my app's proc is stopped without any crash immediately after it started,.

- Only on Samsung GALAXY Note III, only on Lollipop.
- Other phone running Lollipop is ok.
- Samsung GALAXY Note III running KitKat is ok.

My app is using AIDL to provide service for other apps.

`07-27 15:36:24.494: I/libpersona(15754): KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10325
07-27 15:36:24.494: I/libpersona(15754): KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
07-27 15:36:24.524: I/SELinux(15754): Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9008V_5.0_0017
07-27 15:36:24.534: I/ActivityManager(1058): Start proc com.hixxx.ixxx for service com.hixxx.ixxx/.util.RemoteService: pid=15754 uid=10325 gids={50325, 9997, 1028, 1015, 3003} abi=armeabi
07-27 15:36:24.574: D/ResourcesManager(1653): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.hixxx.ixxx-1/base.apk
07-27 15:36:24.584: I/System.out(15427): =========invoked================
07-27 15:36:24.594: V/ApplicationPolicy(1058): isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.hixxx.ixxx
07-27 15:36:24.594: I/ActivityManager(1058): Force stopping com.hixxx.ixxx appid=10325 user=0: from pid 1058
07-27 15:36:24.594: I/ActivityManager(1058): Killing 15754:com.hixxx.ixxx/u0a325 (adj -100): stop com.hixxx.ixxx
07-27 15:36:24.704: I/ActivityManager(1058):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{29add888 u0 com.hixxx.ixxx/.util.RemoteService}`

Comment: An progress on this? I'm facing the same issue in Asus Lollipop too.

Comment: Any progress? The same is happening here!

Comment: I'm facing the same in Samsung Nexus 5 emulator (Android 10)